# Ruby on Rails - error that the system can not locate the partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have a view in this directory:

```
app/views/mobile/dis/my_view.html.haml
```

and in it I have simple one line code to render a partial:

```
= render "dis_content", :preview => false
```

and that partial lives in the same directory as the my_view.html.haml file and is called _dis_content.html.haml

but for some reason when I try to render the my_view.html.haml file, I get this error:

```
Missing partial mobile/dis/dis_content, mobile/base/dis_content, application/dis_content with {:locale=>[:en, :en], :handlers=>[:haml, :erb, :builder]
```

Any idea why it isn't seeing the partial?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
   <%= render 'form' %>
```

or for other folders

```
 <%= render 'layouts/my_other_layouts'%>
```

Comment: hi, the <%= render 'form' %> worked, but the file which has this haml: %p test does not show up on the resulting page.  Any idea why not?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may need

`render :partial => "dis_content"`